# accumulate every value in last three cells in DataFrame in a faster way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a Dataframe df_a:

| date | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 10 | 0 | 10 |
| 2021-01-02 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-03 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2021-01-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-05 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-06 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to accumulate every value in last three cells. For example the df_a will convert into df_b.

| date | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 10 | 0 | 10 |
| 2021-01-03 | 10 | 0 | 10 |
| 2021-01-04 | 15 | 5 | 10 |
| 2021-01-05 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 2021-01-06 | 5 | 5 | 0 |

Now I can use `for loop` but it is really slow. Is there any way to realize it fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas provides a `rolling` function (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

You could probably do something along the lines of `df_b = df_a.rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()`

The min_periods=1 should let you start from the beginning without generating NaNs.